# awk: deleting the rows with empty field?

Tags: awk

hi I have a data that looks like this:

```
a    b    c    1
b    c    d    
c    d    e    6
e    r    w
```

On the 4th column some of the fields are empty and I want to delete the whole row that is missing a field on 4th column so that it looks like the following:

```
a    b    c    1
c    d    e    6
```

I am not sure where to start from to do this. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check the number of fields with `NF`:

```
$ awk 'NF==4' file
a    b    c    1
c    d    e    6
```

To update the file with this, do:

```
awk 'NF==4' file > temp_file && mv temp_file file
```

Comment: Nice to read that! Remember you can accept an answer if you are done

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`,

```
awk '!($4 == "")' yourfile
```